# All permutations of a sum

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm attempting to implement an algorithm that finds all subsets that sum to a number n. Here is my attempt so far:

```
function combos(n, combo, result){
  combo = combo || [];
  result = result || [];

  if(sum(combo) === n) {

    result.push(combo);
    return;
  }

  if(sum(combo) > n) {
    return;
  }

  for(var i = 1; i <=n; i++) {
    var newArr = combo.concat([i]);
    combos(n, newArr, result);
  }

  return result;
}

function sum(array) {
  if(!Array.isArray(array) || array.length === 0){
    return;
  }

  return array.reduce((element, sum) =>{
    return element + sum;
  }, 0); 
}
```

This gives me all combinations. However, there are some redundant solutions. For example.

n = 3 gives [ [ 1, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3 ] ]. When it should be 
[ [ 1, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 3 ] ].

So my problem is I don't know how to jump out of the recursion and not explore the the full breadth of a particular branch. If that makes sense. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I've voted to close as off topic because this site is for reviewing working code, not fixing broken code. The sister site stackoverflow.com is more relevant for the latter, although you should read at least https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask before posting there. However, if I tell you that the standard term for what you want is **partitions of an integer** that may be enough for you to find a solution with your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 1):

#### Return consistent types

Both functions may return different types. For example `combos` may return an array or `undefined`. It would be better to return consistent type from all execution paths.

#### Input validation

The `sum` function does some input validation, checking if its parameter is an array. But this is too late. It's better to do input validation as close to where you receive the input as possible.

Also, there's no need to require nonempty input. If the input is empty, your algorithm will correctly return 0 as sum or empty array for combos, and that's all well.

#### Algorithm

In the current algorithm it's inefficient that the sums of arrays are recomputed every time you add a new element, when you could easily know the sums so far. It would be better to use that knowledge and avoid unnecessary recomputations.

To avoid creating results that are duplicates, your algorithm would need a substantial rewrite, which is off-topic here.